# How to generate Wage/Salary like data which fits a chi squared like distribution given specific mean and variance

Tags: python, scipy, distribution, modeling, chi-squared

I would like to generate wage-salary-like data for a project. So far it is obvious how to generate normally distributed data with a specific mean and variance using `np.random.normal`, but does one know how to model values according to an chi-squared distribution?

I tried `numpy.random.Generator.chisquare` but this does not depend on the moments. For example, I would like to use a specific mean, variance and number of observations.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The mean and variance of a chi-squared distribution are determined by the number of degrees of freedom (`df` and `2*df`, respectively). The numpy generator you are using allows for you to specify `df` and the desired number of samples.

Comment: @foglerit Not quite correct. There is two-parameter chi2, one being df and another parameter being scale (well, there could be a third parameter which is shift).